# Can the "Hot Network Questions" list be filtered?

Tags: support, feature-request, hot-questions-list

Is there any way to filter the list of "Hot Network Questions" which is displayed on the right side of the screen?

I know StackExchange wants to promote their other sites, but I would prefer not to know what's popular on some of the other forums, especially the skeptics forum.  The questions posted on that forum are often insane and disturbing.

Comment: Thank you for bumping this! I've been thinking about how to do this and the linked Greasemonkey scripts are just what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an active feature request [Filter "Hot Network Questions" by excluding sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225297/251274) with [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred). [SE Product manager wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225298/251274):

> We're going to try some algorithm changes to the hot network questions which will try to guess which sites you like and don't like, and give you more of the sites that you like.

While waiting for SE to do something, you may want to hide the hot questions 
entirely. I did this after [What happens if I fart on someone's balls?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159461/what-happens-if-i-fart-on-someones-balls) entered the list. (Not a good fit for the sidebar of serious websites, I think.) Some methods for hiding hot questions are described in [How to avoid "Hot Network Questions" on the sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222721/): AdBlock, userscript, CSS rule. 
I took the CSS way:

```
#hot-network-questions { display: none; }
```